# DHCLIENT not getting the intended static IP configured in DHCP Server

Tags: dhcp, yocto, dhclient, dhcpcd, udhcpc

We have a Linux client that is running a Yocto Thud image. I have set my dhcp to reserve a static address for this client alone.

However, the client still continues to get a dynamic IP from the DHCP Server instead of the intended static IP.

We did some checking and could see that dhclient which was running during the initialization has this behaviour whereas if we remove the package from  yocto. the udhcpc works fine.

However If we include "dhcp-client" package in yocto, the dhclient takes the priority and starts during the init.

Is there something that needs to be done on DHCLIENT side to prevent this issue or is there a way where we can prevent DHCLIENT to run on init unless invoked manually ?